# Get data from style.css file and from from users->your profile

Tags: theme-development

Hi I am new to template development and today I started my first theme.Things are not going as well as I tought I can't seem to find anything I need in the codex it seems to disorganized to me.

I would like to know if there is a function that I can acces the info in the style.css file posted on the top.More specificaly I am interested in geting the author and author URL from these:

```
Theme Name: Twenty Ten
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: The 2010 default theme for WordPress.
Author: wordpressdotorg
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Version: 1.0
```

Another thing I would like to know is how can I get the info for the admin user set in USERS -> YOUR PROFILE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use -**

- [`wp_get_theme()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme)  - To get current theme data. You also can get information of other themes by passing theme directory name.
- [`get_userdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) - To get user data stored in the profile page.